# how to grep each pattern from a line consisting many alike patterns?

Tags: regex, sed, grep

suppose I have a line like the following one:

```
blah blah. Jon abc efg Don. blah blah. Jon afjfa kadkca Don.blah blah.
```

Now I want to get patterns with "Jon" as the first word and "Don" as the last one, with no "Jon" or "Don" in between.That means I want:

```
Jon abc efg Don
Jon afjfa kadkca Don
```

Firstly, I tried

```
egrep -o 'Jon.*Don'
```

But it shows

```
Jon abc efg Don. blah blah. Jon afjfa kadkca Don
```

So I tried to exclude "Don" from middle of the pattern

```
egrep -o 'Jon.*[^(Don)]Don'
```

But it didn't work either.

Comment: please make clear which sample input are multiline and which one are in the same line.

Comment: then your explanation does not make much sense _Now I want to get patterns with "Jon" as the first word and "Don" as the last one_ --> patterns being `.`-separated?

Comment: If I open the file containing the input, gedit shows only one number as the line number not many.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this,

```
grep -oP  'Jon.*?Don' file
```

`egrep` is depreciated which is same as `grep -E` . This won't support non-greedy quantifier. You need to use `-P` perl-regexp parameter to achieve the non-greedy form.

Comment: yeah with `grep -oP` it is working when the patterns are in the same line. But it is not working with `pcregrep` when searching within multilines

Comment: why you go for pcregrep where the `grep -oP` does the job? I think you need to enable `-M` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You should make the `*` lazy by adding a `?` to it, so it will match the lowest number of characters it can.

`grep -oP 'Jon.*?Don'`

Comment: sorry, I forgot `?` isn't supported. Use `grep -oP` instead, because Perl regex supports it.

Comment: I told that 14 mins ago.

Comment: yeah with `grep -oP` it is working when the patterns are in the same line. But it is not working with `pcregrep` when searching within multilines.

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure Jon and Don occur just once by setting them as field separators:

```
awk -F"Jon|Don" '/^Jon/ && /Don$/ && NF==3' file
```

`NF==3` means: there are three fields. Field 1 contains everything up to the first field separator (`Jon`) (so just the beginning of the line), field 2 contains the whole line and field 3 everything from the second field separator (`Don`).

Then, we also check the line starting with `Jon` and ending with `Don` to prevent matching lines like `Don Jon` or `Jon Jon`.

#### Test

```
$ cat a
Jon abc efg Don
Jon afjfa kadkca Don
Jon abc efg Don. blah blah. Jon afjfa kadkca Don
$ awk -F"Jon|Don" '/^Jon/ && /Don$/ && NF==3' a
Jon abc efg Don
Jon afjfa kadkca Don
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I succeeded in removing leading spaces.

awk '{gsub(/blah|./,"")}{gsub(/  Jon/,"Jon")}{sub(/Don /,"Don\n")}1' file 
Jon abc efg Don
Jon afjfa kadkca Don